Sequential, Atomic Task Assignment by Routing Key Across Celery Workers in RabbitMQ
I'm using Celery 5.4 with RabbitMQ 3.13.6, Redis 7.0 to manage a distributed task system. The task input is a distributed fastapi based backend.
And I want workers to process user's tasks in round robin manner based on user id, to avoid starvation.
Here’s my detailed setup and requirement:
Setup
I have 100 Celery workers handling tasks.
10,000 users, each associated with a unique routing key.
Every task takes about 1min - 1hour.
Routing keys increase each time a new user joins, so the queue (Q_0) dynamically gains new routing keys.
Workers should process tasks across all routing keys in a round-robin manner.
Requirement
When a worker is free, it should:
Fetch the next routing key (based on the creation time, i.e., rk1, rk2, …, rkN) and retrieve the oldest available task for that key.
If the worker finishes early, it should proceed with the next routing key.
When reaching the last routing key, the cycle should restart from the first key.
If there are no tasks for a routing key, the worker should skip to the next.
Task assignment must be atomic to avoid any duplicate processing.
What’s Been Tried
I'm looking for the best way to implement this pattern with Celery + RabbitMQ. The goal is to ensure:
Atomic assignment for routing keys.
A round-robin distribution across dynamic routing keys.
Is there a recommended approach or a better solution to achieve this kind of scheduling in Celery with RabbitMQ? Any guidance on configuring or customizing Celery for this specific round-robin requirement would be appreciated!
Currently the task scheduling is not round robin, any solution is appreciated.
